# android Layouts overlapping ListView and LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, overlapping

I am using `FrameLayout` in which I am having a search `Textbox` and `Button` and a `ListView` to be displayed in the next line of the `TextBox`

My layout is like this ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="addCustomers"
        android:text="Add"
        android:textColor="#000000" >
    </Button>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:gravity="bottom" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_customers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I am using this `TextView` to diplay List item in the `ListView`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/txtsimple_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"    
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I have given `margin top` attribute for the `ListView`, but even though it overlaps on the `Button` and `EditText` controls.

I am using a `FrameLayout` but of no use. Please suggest me any help!!
 Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FrameLayout` has no 'rules of placement' so everything just stacks on to each other.

Instead, use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`
or use a `RelativeLayout` and add positioning values to the childs, such as `android:layout_below`

Answer (score 4):

You should use `LinearLayout` as parent, just set `android:orientation="vertical"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/pattern1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="top" >
        ...

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_customers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" >
    ...
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 Neoh and remove imageview, instead put the image as background image attribute at parent view

```
android:background="@drawable/pattern1"
```

Answer (score 1):

FrameLayout are used very less,beacuse they are used to display single view or views which overlaps each other.

So you should use RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1):

FrameLayout is not the best option. You can use other layouts, eg, GridLayout, RelativeLayout or ListView.